# Limit FTP access only to /var/www/ and no other directories

Tags: linux

I have listed a few users on `vsftpd.chroot_list`. I want them to have access to only `/var/www/` and **not** any other directories. I believe, I made necessary changes on the `vsftpd.conf` file. But these users are able to access other directories as well.

My `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file has the following entries:

```
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

##########New Lines#######
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
```

Comment: Can you provide other relevant parts such as under which user account this gets executed initially and so on?

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `vsftpd` as your FTP server, you can easily set-up virtual users and lock them to their directory as described in [this article](http://www.linuxcloudvps.com/blog/setup-virtual-users-in-vsftpd/).

while `vsftpd` is great, `proftpd` may be a bit better with easier (IMO) configuration file.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Lock all the users in home directory, ***** really important *****

DefaultRoot ~

MaxLoginAttempts    5

#VALID LOGINS

<Limit LOGIN>

AllowUser userftp

DenyALL

</Limit>

<Directory /var/www>

Umask 022 022

AllowOverwrite on

#<Limit STOR>

#AllowAll

#</Limit>

<Limit ALL>

Order Allow,Deny

AllowUser userftp

Deny ALL

</Limit>

</Directory>
```

read more at http://www.red87.com/install-proftpd-in-ubuntu-server/